# Can not fix version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android

When try updating to 16.+

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation project(path: 'CordovaLib')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.+'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Gradle **project module** and update google play services from there, because it's telling you that is the plugin that is outdated

Latest version ( as the date of this answer )

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    // ...
}
```

check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) to find the current versions of the google play services plugin.

Tip: avoid using versions like this `1.0.+'` with the + sign, instead , check for the current version of that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

I believe you either need to upgrade that to 16 or remove it if unnecessary

Comment: instead of compile it should be implementation and is not recommended to import all google-services bundle since you can get a multi dex error exeding the 64k method limit. The latest version of that implementation is 4.0.1